# COUNT of joined records in WHERE statement

Tags: sql, join, count, where-clause

I have tables like following:

**post:**

```
id   status
1    0
2    1
3    1
```

**comment:**

```
id   post_id 
1    2
2    1
3    3
4    2
```

I want select posts where status=0 or post have comments. I made this query:

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(cmt.id) as commentsCount FROM `post` `t` LEFT JOIN comment cmt ON (cmt.post_id = t.id) WHERE t.status='0' OR commentsCount>0 GROUP BY t.id
```

but it isn't properly.

How to fix this?

P.s There are only simplified tables to make this easier to understand and in my database I can't add field with count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this condition in a `having` clause:

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(cmt.id) as commentsCount
FROM `post` `t` LEFT JOIN 
      comment cmt
      ON (cmt.post_id = t.id)
WHERE t.status = '0'
GROUP BY t.id 
HAVING commentsCount > 0;
```

EDIT:

For the `or` logic, you can move both conditions to the `having` clause:

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(cmt.id) as commentsCount
FROM `post` `t` LEFT JOIN 
      comment cmt
      ON (cmt.post_id = t.id)
GROUP BY t.id 
HAVING max(t.status) = '0' OR commentsCount > 0;
```

The `max()` is, strictly speaking, unnecessary because `id` is a primary key.  But I'm including it for clarity.

Comment: But posts not necessarily have comments, but only if status is different than '0'

Answer (score 1):

There is also more straightforward way to translate your query from English to SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM post
WHERE status='0'
  or (select count(1) from comment where post_id = post.id) > 0
```

I recommend you to check which query has better plan on your data (with join or with subquery). Anyway special field for filtering is highly recommended in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In your group by clause you will need all the fields in your select clause apart from the ones with aggregate functions. So your query will be:

```
SELECT t.id, t.status, COUNT(cmt.id) as commentsCount FROM `post` `t` 
LEFT JOIN comment cmt ON (cmt.post_id = t.id) 
WHERE t.status='0' OR commentsCount>0 GROUP BY t.id, t.status
```

Also, as status will always be zero, you may probably leave it out from both your select and group by clause.

```
SELECT t.id, COUNT(cmt.id) as commentsCount FROM `post` `t` 
LEFT JOIN comment cmt ON (cmt.post_id = t.id) 
WHERE t.status='0' OR commentsCount>0 GROUP BY t.id
```